# How do I return a 401 status instead of a 302 redirect after cookie has expired?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, ws-federation

I'm using cookie authentication without Identity and the following Nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation" Version="2.0.3" />
```

I'm setting a short timeout on my cookie and wanting my API calls to return a 401 status instead of a 302 redirect when the cookie has expired. My `ConfigureServices` looks like the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IRestService, RestService>();

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("AspNetCookieShare")
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration["DataProtectionKeyDirectory"]));

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddWsFederation(options =>
        {
            options.Wtrealm = Configuration["Wtrealm"];
            options.MetadataAddress = "http://example.com/metadata.xml";
            options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.Name = "AspNetShared";
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";

            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I'm using OnRedirectToLogin, however, I'm still getting 302 response and not a 401 after the cookie has expired:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because WsFed is your default challenge scheme, I think that's where you need to intercept the redirect. I haven't set up auth this way, but basically I think the cookie portion is tracking the sign-in but WsFed actually controls it.

Comment: @McGuireV10 thank you. You pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Cookie Auth and WsFed are poorly suited for WebAPIs, look at JwtBearer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed my `services.AddWsFederation()` to the following and it appears to be working:

```
.AddWsFederation(options =>
{
    options.Wtrealm = Configuration["Wtrealm"];
    options.MetadataAddress = "http://example.com/metadata.xml";
    options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
})
```

Comment: On what file should that go?

Comment: @Gregory in `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices()`. Although I haven't used this in awhile so I'm not sure if this is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Tested for TargetFramework = net6.0

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        ...
        options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
    });
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
```

```
public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    public override Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task RedirectToAccessDenied(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```